# How to find out my dependency property changed ?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Dependency Property like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowTooltipProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register(
"ShowTooltip",
  typeof(bool),
  typeof(customtextbox),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
 public bool ShowTooltip
    {
        get
        { return (string)GetValue(ShowTooltipProperty);}
        set
        {SetValue(ShowTooltipProperty, value); }
 }
```

I want when my property changed i  call a method.How to i find out my property changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [overload for `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557299.aspx) which allows you to specify a property changed callback.